# Derivation of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-decomposition

My question is about how can reach to the formula $$\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=-A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}$$ when $A$ is a matrix. It is very similar to $$\frac{dx^{-1}}{dt}=-x^{-2}\frac{dx}{dt}$$And I know we can write $$A^{-1}=A^{-1}I\\A^{-1}=A^{-1}AA^{-1}$$ then it seems to be $$\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}AA^{-1} +A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}+A^{-1}A\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}$$ in this part: how can I simplify right hand side? to obtain $\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=-A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}$
Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You can expand $(A + H)^{-1}$ as a geometric series, then the derivative is the first order term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your bottom line:
$$\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}I+A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}+I\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}
\\=2I\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}+A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}$$
which rearranges to:
$$-\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}$$
which is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the identity
$$ \def\A{A^{-1}}  I \;=\; \A A $$
Differentiate each side
$\left({\rm using}\;dA\;{\rm to\ denote}\;{\large\frac{dA}{dt}}\right)$
$$ 0 \;=\; d\A A \;+\; \A\,dA $$
Solve for $d\A$
$$ d\A = - \A\;dA\;\A $$